# Why does RStudio save my vector as a string?

Tags: r

I have having trouble saving objects with RStudio.  Below is my console.  Why does data turn out to be a string and not a vector?

```
> test=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> save(test,file="G:/R/Projects/Forecast Assymetry/Output/result.Rdata")
> data<-load(file="G:/R/Projects/Forecast Assymetry/Output/result.Rdata")
> data
[1] "test"
```

Comment: I think you just want to `load`. Once you do that, `test` will exist.

Comment: to clarify: don't assign the results of `load` to `data`.  The behaviour you're expecting is what you would get from `saveRDS`/`readRDS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do

```
test=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
save(test, file = "G:/R/Projects/Forecast Assymetry/Output/result.Rdata")
rm(test)
load(file = "G:/R/Projects/Forecast Assymetry/Output/result.Rdata")
test
```

This will work, you don't want to point your load to anything, it will simply conserve the object names.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `load` (see `?load`) is

```
"A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly."
```

which is what you are getting. There is however an object created by the name of `test` already in your workspace. For example, try:

```
str(test)
```

after the load command.